# Opencv Pythonprogram

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying opencv with python now.
What mean this error?

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in Mat, file /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 269 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "sabun5.py", line 16, in <module> 
img_m = cv2.threshold(img_df, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] 
cv2.error: /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:269: error: (-215) m.dims >= 2 in function Mat
```

Comment: it looks like it needs some 2-dimensional element but it gets 1-dimensional element.

Comment: I guess that your `img_df ` is not loaded properly, maybe the path is not correct, so before calling `cv2.threshold()`, call `print img_df.shape` to check if the image is loaded properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold), that the threshold function just allow single-channel images.

If your image is a color one, it won't work. If it's grayscale but you are loading it with imread, it might be possible that OpenCV load it as a 3-channel one. You can add the flag to load it as a single-channel with CV_8UC1 (supposing it is an 8 bit unsigned one, which is the more common for a grayscale image).
For example:
img_df = cv2.imread("image/path", cv2.CV_8UC1)

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the image into grayscale before thresholding your image has more then two dimentions i.e (height,width,color-channel) gray scale image has only two dimention(height,width)
it might help

```
    import cv2
    img = cv.imread('x.png',0)
    # where 0 converts the image in grayscale or gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,    cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    img_m = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] 

    cv2.waitKey(0)
```